# How to use a variable in browser and node context in puppeteer $$eval function?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I have passed the inputData variable as an optional argument to $$eval function to make it accessible in node context. Though facing an error that inputData is undefined.

```
list = await page.$$eval(inputData.LIST, lists => lists.map(list => ({
            Name     : list.querySelector(inputData.NAME).innerText,
            Currency : list.querySelector('.price-per-sellable-unit .currency') !== null ?
                       list.querySelector('.price-per-sellable-unit .currency').innerText :               
                       "Out of stock",
            Price    : list.querySelector('.price-per-sellable-unit .value') !== null ?
                       list.querySelector('.price-per-sellable-unit .value').innerText :               
                       "Out of stock"
    })), inputData);
```

Error msg :

```
(node:3068) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: inputData is not defined
    at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:2:43
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:1:17
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the second parameter mentioned:

```js
list = await page.$$eval(inputData.LIST, (lists, inputData) => lists.map(list => {
            //                                   ^ here
  })), inputData);
```